# Lost Sri Vaishanva Literature/Works

Tags: scripture, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

How many or I can say which [Sri Vaishnava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Vaishnavism) works(literature) are lost or exist as citations in other literature?

Comment: There are a lot of lost Sri Vaishnava works, but what comes to mind immediately Yoga Rahasya and Nyaya Tattva of Nathamuni, the Kashmiri Agama Pramanya of Yamunacharya, the Purusha Nirnaya which may have been written by either Nathamuni or Yamunacharya, and some Tamil works of Ramanujacharya.  (Only Ramanujacharya's Sanskrit works survive, other than a few Tamil invocatory verses he composed about various Alwars.)

Comment: Also, this web page lists 11 lost works of Vedanta Desikan: http://www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/ebooks/vdesikan/works.html And by the way, there are also works that are partially lost, like Yamunacharya's Siddhitrayam, Vedanta Desikan's Satadhushani, and Periavachan Pillai's commentary on the Periyalwar Thirumozhi.  By the way, Manavala Mamunigal noticed that Periyavachan Pillai's commentary was lost for 40 verses of the Periyalwar Thriumozhi, and so he decided to write his own commentary on just those 40 verses.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Why don't you post an answer..

Comment: Looks too-broad question.